# Kube API for Listing the CustomResource instances in a namespace (or on a cluster) in Kubernetes

Tags: rest, kubernetes, client-go, kubernetes-custom-resources

Using command-line utility `kubectl` we can list a custom resource instances as follows

```
kubectl get <customresource_kind>
```

In a similar fashion, do we have a REST API to achieve the same? i.e. the API takes the Kind of the CustomResource and lists all the instances created?

I am referring to this API Reference :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/

Answer (score 1):

You can list crds like every other API resources using Kubernetes REST API.

The final URL path will differ, depending on object's scope: `Cluster` or `Namespaced`.

The general rule for constructing the URL path is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#standard-api-terminology) in official documentation.

Just to give you an example based on calico's [clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org (v1)](https://gist.github.com/nepomucen/bd091b509ae60f6948969d859878e568#file-crds-yaml-L324):

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &

curl http://localhost:8080/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations | jq '.items[].metadata.name

"default" <- I have only one instance of this type of custom resource
```